# VB.NET SQLite "constraint failed" when calling Update on DataAdapter?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sqlite

I am adding an object to a DataTable, which is part of the Tables collection of a DataSet.  Then I am calling Update on a DataAdapter associated with the previously mentioned DataTable.  However, when I call Update, it is throwing an exception saying "NOT NULL constraint failed: proxies.port".  I will share the code that I am using to create the database, load it's data, and even the constructor of the Proxy object I am using.  First to answer correctly gets the check mark :)

Thanks!

```
Public Sub CreateDB()
    Dim dbLocation As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\data.s3db"
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(dbLocation)
    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection("DataSource=" & dbLocation & ";Version=3;")
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE proxies (
                                ip Text  Not NULL,
                                port Integer  Not NULL,
                                countryName Text  Not NULL,
                                pingTime Integer  Not NULL,
                                status Text  Not NULL,
                                PRIMARY KEY (ip, port),
                                unique(ip, port)
                            );
                            CREATE TABLE [judges] (
                                [id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                [url] TEXT  UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                                [pingTime] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
                                [status] TEXT  NOT NULL
                            );
                            CREATE TABLE [tests] (
                                [id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                [url] TEXT  NULL,
                                [validationText] TEXT  NOT NULL,
                                [invalidationText] TEXT  NOT NULL,
                                [status] TEXT  NOT NULL
                            )"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

And am loading this data in a sub like so:

```
Public Sub LoadDataFromDB()
    Using connection As New SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString)
        dbDataSet.Tables.Add("proxies")
        dbProxyAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet.Tables("proxies"))
        Dim cmdBuilder As New SQLiteCommandBuilder(dbProxyAdapter)
        dbProxyAdapter.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand
        Dim proxy As New Proxy("1.1.1.1:12345")
        dbDataSet.Tables("proxies").Rows.Add(proxy)
        dbProxyAdapter.Update(dbDataSet.Tables("proxies"))
    End Using
End Sub
```

Proxy Object Constructor

```
Public Sub New(proxy As String)
    If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(proxy, "(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d{2,5}") Then
        Me.IP = proxy.Split(":")(0)
        Me.Port = proxy.Split(":")(1)
        Me.PingTime = 0
        Me.Status = ProxyStatus.Unknown
        Me.CountryName = "Unknown"
    Else
        Throw New Exception("Invalid proxy string '" & proxy & "'")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should  show your update command to solve problem

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.

By creating a DataRow object and returning dbDataSet.Tables("proxies").NewRow(), then setting each columns value likeso: row.Item("ip") = value, and finally adding this row to the DataTable within my DataSet, the NOT NULL constraint is satisfied when calling Update on the DataAdapter.  The question still remains, why is the ItemArray of the Proxy object not translating correctly, the column names match the Proxy objects public property names.  Oh well, I don't feel like contemplating it, my workaround will do because it solves my headache, with a few extra lines of code than I had hoped....